# Deployment to the particular Kubernetes cluster node

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to implement the CI/CD pipeline using Kubernetes , Jenkins with my private SVN repository. And I am planning to use Kubernetes cluster having 3 master and 15 worker machine/Node. And Using Jenkins to deploy the microservice developed using spring boot. So When I am deploying using Jenkins , How I can define which microservice need to deploy in which node in kubernetes cluster?. Do I need to specify in Pod ? Or Any other definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes figures out what nodes should run what pods. You don't have to do that. You have to indicate how much memory and cpu each pod needs, k8s to a first approximation figures out the rest.

That said, what you do have to do is figure out how to partition the full set of workloads you need to run- say, by environment (dev/stage/prod), or by tenant (team X/team Y/team Z or client X/client Y/client Z)- into namespaces, then figure out what workflow makes sense for that partitioning, then configure the CI to satisfy that workflow.

Comment: Are you saying that I don't have permission to specify which pod need to run in which node? . So If I have 3 master and 15 nodes, then How i will call the deployed microservice from my angular 2 application ? . We need to have its node IP and port. So how can call if i don't know the node which deployed my pods ?

Comment: And my second confusion is that - How I need to partition these all ? If i am keeping both staging and dev in my organization's on-premise server , then I only need to make AWS Ec2 as live ( Including Blue-green deployment strategy). And If I am using staging and live both in Ec2 - then how i can partition my cluster among these 15 nodes ?

Comment: Also  clarify your statement "figure out what workflow makes sense for that partitioning"  please? Still having lot of confusion

Comment: To make something available for an angular2 client, use an Ingress or Service resource on kubernetes. Those create a publicly-visible load balancer on AWS, which is kept updated on the locations of pods on the worker nodes.

Comment: Namespaces are logical groupings, and have resource limits. If you have staging and prod on kubernetes, create separate Namespaces for each and assign the deployed applications to the appropriate namespaces. You don't need to partition or otherwise worry about worker nodes. Kubernetes will handle the physical assignment of pods to worker nodes.

Comment: Workflow: you might have CICD into staging (in a Staging Namespace), and then do some testing, then create a new environment in prod (in a Prod Namespace), test, then manually blue-green switch over. Or maybe use a Blue namespace and a green Namespace. There are a lot of variations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170588/discussion-between-prince-varghese-v-and-jonah-benton).

Answer (score 3):

> How I can define which microservice need to deploy in which node in kubernetes cluster?. Do I need to specify in Pod ? Or Any other definition ?

- As said in other answers you don't **need** to do this, but you **can** if there is any reason to do so using deprecated nodeSelector or preferable affinities. They are well worth the time to read since you can have some pods relating to specific services/microservices group together or away from each other across available nodes to allow for more flexible and resilient architecture and proper spread out. This way you are helping scheduler deciding where to place what to achieve desired layout. For most basic needs previously mentioned resource allocation can do the trick but for any fine graining you have affinity (and anti affinity) at your disposal. Documentation detailing this is here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/